# Informatica - Null character issue in from Flat Source file

Tags: null, character, informatica

I am trying to import data from a fixed flat file to oracle database. 
However when a data is starting with * that data is converted into NULL. I tried various options in the advanced properties of my fixed file but it isn't resolving the issue. An example of it would be 
My source file contain data like

subbu

s*bbu

*ubbu

If I load the data into target it loads like

subbu

s*bbu

NULL

"*ubbu" becomes NULL since in Fixed-width file null

Does anyone has some solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source file properties in the session, change the NULL character to something else.

[image]